# is a convex continuous function absolutely continuous

Tags: real-analysis, sobolev-spaces

Does a continuous convex function $\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ belong to $W^{1,1}_{loc}$ ?

thank you.

Comment: What do you know about differentiability of convex functions?

Comment: Not much (or say nothing), any readings or references would be appreciated.

Comment: One characterisation of convexity is that the difference quotients $$\frac{f(y) - f(x)}{y-x}$$ where $x\neq y$ are increasing in each variable when the other is fixed. Can you see how that relates to differentiability?

Comment: this would give me existence of right and left derivative everywhere ? moreover left derivative is less or equal then right derivative.

Comment: Ok maybe I have better, the function will be lipischitz in every compact set. So that it will be absolutely continuous.

Comment: Right, you can argue with that. That's probably the shortest way.

Comment: Thx very much, very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is true. In fact, it is locally in $W^{1,p}$ for any $p\in [1,\infty]$ because [a convex function is locally Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/148599/).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is true. A convex function is always continuous and actually locally Lipschitz. @Yes already provided you a nice proof in 1-D but let me point out that this result also holds in high-dimensions.

That is, given $f: \mathbb R^N\to \mathbb R$ is convex, we have $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $\mathbb R^N$. You can find proof at page 236 in this [book](https://books.google.com/books/about/Measure_Theory_and_Fine_Properties_of_Fu.html?id=HZONacVPGlMC&hl=en), and also some more results of Convex function regarding to Sobolev spaces.