# A convex lower semicontinuous function, but discontinuous?

Tags: real-analysis, optimization

Working on Hilbert space, is it possible to find a real valued convex lower semicontinuous function in which it does not continuous at any point in a space. If not, how can we prove it?

Comment: No. Note that a convex function is locally Lipshitz, see, eg, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148599/proving-that-a-convex-function-is-lipschitz)

Comment: Convexity implies continuity at every point except possibly the end points, so this is not possible.

Comment: Sorry, I should discuss with a Hilbert space, is it possible?

Comment: @Thomas, convex $\textbf{continous}$ functions in a normed space are locally Lipschitz, but not every convex function is continuous in a normed space, so this question is legit

Comment: @Magnusseen yes, you are right. Thanks for pointing that out. The answer to the question can still be given and can be found, e.g., here: http://www.mat.unimi.it/users/libor/AnConvessa/continuity.pdf