# Can a function be neither convex nor concave everywhere?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, continuity, convex-analysis

For a simpliest example, define continuous $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be locally convex in neighborhood $U\subset\mathbb R$ if $\{y>f(x)|x\in U\}$ is a convex set.

$f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ to be locally concave in $U\subset\mathbb R$ if $\{y<f(x)|x\in U\}$ is a convex set.

Say $f$ is neither convex nor concave everywhere if $f$ is neither locally concave nor convex in all neighborhood set $U\subset\mathbb R$ and $|U|>3$. Is it possible? (I guess yes)

Say $f$ is neither convex nor concave everywhere if $f$ is neither locally concave nor convex in all measure non zero  neighborhood set $U\subset\mathbb R$. Is it possible? (I guess no)

Comment: Yes in both cases. Take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blancmange_curve#Convergence_and_continuity) for an idea.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) provides an example of a function that is continuous but not convex or concave in any open neighborhood.

[image: Weierstrass function]

The reason being that it has infinitely fine oscillation everywhere (since it is a [fractal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal)). It is defined by the infinite series
$$
f(x):=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a^n \cos(b^n \pi x)
$$
where $a,b\in \Bbb R$ satisfy certain assumptions. You can read more about it in the wikipedia link I provided.

To see why this function has such properties, we recall that if $f$ is convex/concave, then [it is (locally) Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148599/proving-that-a-convex-function-is-lipschitz). However, [Rademacher's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rademacher%27s_theorem) says that a Lipschitz continuous function is differentiable almost everywhere, which contradicts the fact that our $f$ is nowhere differentiable.