# If $f$ is a real-valued function and is convex on an open interval $(a,b)$, show that $f$ is bounded on any closed subset $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification, convex-analysis

I read on a post that to prove *a real function that is convex on an open interval is bounded on any closed subset* is straightforward, so I wanted to give it a shot. However, I noticed that my approach seemed a little more convoluted than I had anticipated, which makes me think that my strategy is misguided. Any tips would be appreciated. Cheers.

---

Without assuming differentiability or continuity, prove the following:

> If $f$ is a real-valued function and is convex on an open interval $(a,b)$, show that $f$ is bounded on any closed subset $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$

I will show that on an arbitrary $[c,d]$, $f$ has a lower-bound. The argument for an upper bound works similarly.

---

From the definition of continuity, we have the following:

$$\forall x_1,x_2,x_3 \in (a,b): x_1 \lt x_2 \lt x_3 \rightarrow\frac{f(x_3)-f(x_1)}{x_3-x_1} \gt  \frac{f(x_2)-f(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}$$

Rearranging the inequality, noting that $x_3 -x_1 \gt 0$, we have that:

$$f(x_3)\gt \frac{x_3-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big]+f(x_1) \quad (\dagger_1)$$

In order to get this inequality in the desired form, we need to get rid of the $x_3$ symbol in the right-hand side of the inequality.

There are two cases: $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \geq 0$ or $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \lt 0$. Suppose the former.

**Case 1: $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \geq 0$**

Consider an arbitrary closed interval $[c,d]$ such that $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$.

Referencing $(\dagger_1)$, let $x_3 =x \in [c,d]$ and let $x_1, x_2 \in(a,c)$ such that $x_1 \lt x_2$. Next, consider some $k \in (a,c)$.

Firstly, note that because $x \gt k$, we have that $\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \gt\frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$. By assumption, $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \geq 0$; therefore, we have the following:

\begin{align}f(x) \gt \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1)\geq \frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1) \end{align}

which means that $f(x) \gt \frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1)=m$. Noting that $x$ was an arbitrary element of $[c,d]$, let $m$ be a lower bound of $f$ on $[c,d]$.

Now suppose that $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \lt 0$.

**Case 2: $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \lt 0$**

The set up is similar, but this time we stipulate that $k \in (d,b)$. As such, we must have that $x \lt k$. This means that $\frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1} \lt \frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}$. By assumption, $f(x_2)-f(x_1) \lt 0$; therefore, we have the following:

\begin{align}f(x) \gt \frac{x-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1)\gt \frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1) \end{align}

which means that $f(x) \gt \frac{k-x_1}{x_2-x_1}\cdot\big[f(x_2)-f(x_1)\big] +f(x_1)=m'$.  Noting that $x$ was an arbitrary element of $[c,d]$, let $m'$ be a lower bound of $f$ on $[c,d]. \quad \square$

Comment: Yes, this can be done much more simply. Hint: $\lambda f(c) + (1 - \lambda) f(d) \le \max\{f(c), f(d)\}$ for all $\lambda \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy The proof I am working on to **prove** that convex functions are continuous requires that I show that convex functions are bounded.

Comment: @TheoBendit perhaps a dumb question, but the hint that you have recommended seems to only address the "show that there is an upper bound" for any closed subinterval. What about for lower bounds?

Comment: Not a dumb question, I just gave an incomplete response. I would approach the lower bound much as Stinking Bishop has done.

Comment: @TheoBendit the other approach I was thinking of, which may fall into the category "straightforward approaches", is to show that any tangent line at a point along the convex interval necessarily sits below (or touching) the graph of $f$. This means that any arbitrary $[c,d] \subset (a,b)$ necessarily sits above (or touching) this arbitrary tangent line.

Comment: That's not a bad idea. You'd have to establish that a tangent exists. You could use the three slope lemma to establish that such a tangent must exist at any given point (though it need not be unique).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**: If the function $f$ is convex, then the graph of it on $[c,d]$ is bounded from above by the straight line connecting $(c, f(c))$ and $(d, f(d))$.

For the bound "below", construct two straight lines: $l_1(x)$ connecting $(a, f(a))$ with $(c, f(c))$ and $l_2(x)$, connecting $(b, f(b))$ with $(d, f(d))$. The piecewise-linear function that goes from $(c, f(c))$ alongside $l_1$ until the intersection of $l_1$ with $l_2$ and then goes alongside $l_2$ until $(d, f(d))$ bounds $f$ from below.

---

(In fact, $l_1$ and $l_2$ are also bounded on $[c,d]$, being linear, so *any* of those two functions is a lower bound for $f$. In the above, the piecewise-linear function is actually $\max(l_1(x), l_2(x))$ and makes for a slightly finer lower bound.)

Comment: very visually intuitive. Cheers~

Answer (score 0):

A much simpler argument is to use the fact that a convex function in a domain is continuous in the interior of its domain, so $f$ will be actually continuous in $(a,b)$, hence bounded on any compact subset.

Comment: The proof I am working on to **prove** that convex functions are continuous requires that I show that convex functions are bounded.

Comment: @S. Cramer. I see. One can always find a longer path; it is the shorter ones that are harder to come by. It is actually possible to prove continuity using the "three-point" lemma on convex functions, the one that compares the slopes of the chords of the graph.

Answer (score 0):

Let $e=(a+c)/2$ and $e'=(d+b)/2$ and $e''=(e+c)/2.$

(1). Let $g=\max \{sf(e)+(1-s)f(e'):s\in [0,1]\}.$ For each $x\in [c,d]$ there exists $r\in (0,1)$ with $x=re+(1-r)e',$ so $$f(x)=f(re+(1-r)e')\le rf(e)+(1-r)f(e')\le g.$$ So $f$ on $[c,d]$ is bounded above by the number $g.$

(2).  For any $x\in [c,d]$ we have $e''=re+(1-r)x$ where $r=\frac {x-e''}{x-e}\in [\frac 1 2 , \frac {d-e''}{d-e}]\subset [0,1].$  So we have  $$\bullet\quad f(e'')\le rf(e)+(1-r)f(x).$$ Now $(1-r)^{-1}=\frac {x-e}{e-e''}\ge \frac {c-e}{e-e''}=2.$ And $f(e'')-rf(e)\ge -|f(e'')|-r|f(e)|\ge -|f(e'')|-|f(e)|.$ Therefore  by $\bullet$ we have $$f(x)\ge (1-r)^{-1}(f(e'')-rf(e))\ge 2(-|f(e'')|-|f(e)|).$$

Answer (score 0):

You can show that f is Lioschitz on$ [c,d]$. It's done here!

[Proving that a convex function is Lipschitz](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/148599/proving-that-a-convex-function-is-lipschitz)